# How to get all merged commits in git that includes a specific sentence?

Tags: python-3.x, git

I want to write a function that get all merged commits on my master, and check for merged commits with a specific sentence.

I have written this function, and it gets only the last commit that includes this sentence, it is as shown here:

```
def get_commit_message():
commit_message = subprocess.check_output(["git", "log", "-1", "--pretty=format:\'%B\'", "--grep","THE REQUIRED CHANGES"], stderr=subprocess.STDOUT).decode("utf-8").split('\n')
return commit_message
```

How can i find each and every merged commit message in master that has "THE REQUIRED CHANGES" in it, and not only the last one that has it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`git log -1 ...` will limit the output of `git log` to one single commit.

Drop the `-1`.

Comment: Thanks, this helped!

Comment: good ! if this answers your question, tick the answer to mark it as accepted.